# Copying only non-existent files in ant

Tags: java, ant, copy, java-web-start

I'm deploying my project to a web-server to be deployed with java Web Start. However, Web Start uses modification date to figure out whether to download the resources again (by default).

What I want is a way to only deploy those (jar) files that do not already exist. This is made possible by having build-version numbers on all my jars, so 2 jars with the same name have *the same contents*.

Notes:

- The jar modification dates will always be newer in the build (which is why I'm getting this problem), due to downloading from svn or ivy
- There's a way to do this using sun's download servlet, more files etc, but I'm lazy, don't need it, and this (simpler) solution will be more robust in the long term

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not a Maven user, but isn't this what Maven is used for?

Comment: Potentially, but from what I've heard, Maven is not for predictable builds that will *just work* in 2 years time. I use ant because what I want is either very trivial to implement, or very specific.

Comment: You want to only copy but not override the jars, right? Stupid question: why is the ant Copy task not working (its attribute overwrite is defaulted to false so the behaviour should be: copy but not override?)

Comment: overwrite=false means that it will not copy same or older files.  Since this is a build, the files' modification date is now, so it will always overwrite. Which then causes webstart to re-download...

Answer (score 15):

If you are using ants copy task (you don't explicitly say you are), you could try the `present` selector: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect.

```
<copy todir="target">
  <fileset dir="src">
    <present targetdir="target" present="srconly" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could attempt to set the [`granularity` attribute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) very, very high, to basically disable the "copy files with the same name if the source file is newer than the destination" feature.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, and I wound up implementing my own jar task to do what I needed. The Ant source code is a good place to start; if you're lucky you might be able to just subclass Ant's jar task. It's not nearly as difficult as it might sound, and was much more straightforward than the half dozen workarounds I tried or considered.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue with maven and [JavaFX and WebStart Plugin](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/JP/JavaFX+Compiler+Maven+Plugin) that keeps maven layout and version in the JNLP, and using "non-unique" SNAPSHOT will keep the same jar (ignoring the timestamp).

I know it's maven so not good for you, but someone may give it a try?